# Why is "emerged" in "She emerged from the divorce a stronger person" marked only as intransitive but not as linking?

Tags: transitivity, dictionaries, linking-verbs

All dictionaries which mark their verbs with the labels: "transitive", "intransitive" and "linking", for some reason, don't write that the verb "*emerge*" has a meaning where it acts as linking. For example:

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/emerge):
**(1)** *She emerged from the divorce a stronger person*.

As far as I understand, the "*emerged*" is linking here. So if a dictionary uses such a designation as "linking", then it must write the verb "*emerged*" in (1) is linking. Why does this not happen?

What is the verb "*emerge*" different in from all other verbs marked as *linking* in dictionaries?

update:
I think the "*emerged*" in (1) is linking because the dictionary says it's intransitive here, i.e. "*a stronger person*" is not a direct object, therefore, it's related to a subject complement, i.e. the "*emerged*" is linking here.

Comment: Why do you think _emerge_ is a 'linking verb'?

Comment: @KateBunting I answered your question at the end of the original post.

Comment: "Emerge" takes a PC (predicative complement), as in "She emerged a stronger person", where the NP "a stronger person" is PC with "she" as predicand. Some people consider such verbs 'linking' verbs'.

Comment: If you consider the semantic roles in the OP's sentence, "emerge" is [used with "from"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emerge) to construct what is in terms of meaning a two-place predicate (there is an agent and a source linked together). In terms of meaning it is the same as "she exited the divorce", which is transitive. (This is why dividing up verbs into categories is a bit silly.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your "update", it appears that you are defining "linking verb" as any intransitive verb that takes a subject complement. However, just about any verb can take a subject complement, and it would not make sense to categorize all intransitive verbs as "linking verbs".

Why do I say that just about any verb can take a subject complement? Looking around my room, I see a pair of headphones. Let me then use a different verb with your subject complement:

> She took off the headphones before exercising and then put them back on a stronger person.

I hope that you can see how easy it is to use just about any verb (even a transitive phrasal verb such as "put on") with a subject complement. Therefore, your definition doesn't seem to be very useful for categorizing linking verbs.

It is more common to define "linking verb" as a verb that requires a subject complement. If you replaced "put them back on a stronger person" with "was", "seemed", "became", etc., then I think that you will realize that those versions are ungrammatical without subject complements. [CoGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) says the following (section 16.21):

> A verb is said to have copular complementation when it is followed by a subject complement (C<sub>s</sub>) or a predication adjunct, and when this element cannot be dropped without changing the meaning of the verb.

Comment: I don't follow you. Where is the subject complement in your example?

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps because you follow H&P and I generally don't. I consider "a stronger person" to be a subject complement in that example.

Comment: A subject complement (PC) in the OP's example, but in yours it's surely an NP  complement of the preposition "on".

Comment: @BillJ Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, it could mean that she put the headphones on another person, but not "surely". Furthermore, the fact that she exercised suggests that she was the one who got stronger. I could come up with a clearer example if you really object, but I think that the intended meaning is pretty clear. (Thank you for pointing out the issue, though; I didn't even realize it when writing that example.)

Comment: In your suggested meaning of your example, (which is reasonable) the NP "a stronger person" is a not a complement but a predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand ("she") and an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure. We might also argue that "a stronger person" is not a modifier but a supplementary adjunct, one that is not integrated into clause structure but set apart by intonation and (usually) punctuation.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I'm sure that everything that you've said is correct according to H&P. As I've said to you here and many times previously, I generally don't follow H&P.